# Run-time error '1004'. in copy/paste as picture

Tags: vba, excel

I get Run-time error '1004' when trying to copy a range of cells and doing a paste as a picture.

### Description of the Excel file:

I have 1 Excel file that has 2 sheets:

- Sheet1 - it has a table with data
- Sheet2 - it has a Pivot Table that reads the data from the table in Sheet1

(I created this small Excel only for replication purposes as I have the issue in a much bigger Excel file.)

### Description of the issue:

I have a macro to copy the range of cells that contains the Pivot Table and paste it as a picture.

The macro is running correctly with no errors in my laptop and in other colleagues' laptops. Some colleagues are getting the error in their laptops.

We all are using:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits
- Office 365 ProPlus (Excel 2016)

### Macro created:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("CS - Pivot Tables")

With ws
    .Activate
    .Range("B2:D13").Copy
    .Range("L2").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

*****  the macro stops on `.Pictures.Paste`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a different copy to copy pictures:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("CS - Pivot Tables")

    With ws
        .Activate
        .Range("B2:D13").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Range("B1").Select
        .Paste
    End With


Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @Vityata, yeah there are a few ways to solve the question :)

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this !!!  I tried both solutions they work well in my PC.  I then asked my colleague to try them. The one provided by VBA Pete is working correcly !!!! However, the one provided by Vityata is shooting the same error we used to have. I am going to try to apply the solution in my code confirm that the whole macro works fine. I will keep you posted.  Thanks again. Alberto

Comment: No worries Alberto, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this:

```
Sub Macro4()

    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    dim pic     as picture

    Set ws = Sheets("CS - Pivot Tables")
    With ws 
        .Activate 
        .Range("B2:D13").Copy 
        .Range("L2").Select 
        set pic = .pictures.paste
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

(Your code is not formatted, but I am guessing I did it right).